# Milter: from=<address@domain.com> reject=451 4.3.2 Please try again later

Tags: email-server, zimbra

We have a Zimbra mail server and we are facing some issues from other MTAs trying to verify recipients.

The other MTA (spam filtering, etc.) is getting the following error:

```
Milter: from=<address@domain.com> reject=451 4.3.2 Please try again later
```

We are checking `milter.log` but we don't get any conection from the other MTA. Besides, milter filters are only for distribution lists and the addresses showing out in the errors are user names, not distributions lists.

It is also quite strange that the system is working after a kind of reset but after a while we are getting back the errors.

Any idea of what could be?

Comment: You could look at /var/log/zimbra.log for error messages.

Comment: Nothing there. We have increased the log level just in case